# Activate some bits of a number in C

Tags: c, bit

I need to implement the function ***int activate_bits(int a, int left, int right)*** that should ’activate’
all the bits to the left of left and to the right of right on the number a (excluding the bits left and
right).

So far I've came up with this:

```
int activate_bits(int a, int left, int right)
{
    int n, j, mask, masked_a;

    for (n = 1; n < left; n++) {
        mask = 1 << n;
        masked_a = a | mask;
    }

    for (j = 31; j > right; j--) {
        mask = 1 >> j;
        masked_a = a | mask;
    }

    return masked_a;
}
```

Can anyone help me to why the ***masked_a*** it's not correct or fix my faulty code?

Comment: By 'activate', do you mean 'set' (as in set to binary 1)?

Comment: Are you given  the prototype? Otherwise I would suggest working with unsigned types.

Comment: I think your left loop is off-by-one. Is right passed as a number of bits, i.e. 1 means |= 0x8000000, or the limit i.e. 1 means |= 0xfffffffe ? `>>` is probably wrong too, unless it wraps which I don't think it does.

Comment: It would be a good idea to use sizeof(int) - 1 instead of 31 in case your code ever runs on a platform where an int is not 32 bits.

Comment: @jmq may want to recalculate that. on a 32bit int architecture, that would be .. *3*. not 31. You need to work a `CHAR_BIT` multiplier or something similar into that equation.

Comment: Oh, and as per J.Z.'s answer, are you mixing left and right up? Is left most-significant bits and right least significant bits? Example inputs and outputs please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you need to be setting `masked_a` to `a` before looping:

```
int activate_bits(int a, int left, int right)
{
    int n, j, mask, masked_a;

    masked_a = a;

    for (n = 0; n < left; n++) {
        mask = 0x80000000 >> n;
        masked_a = masked_a | mask;
    }

    for (j = 0; j < right; j++) {
        mask = 1 << j;
        masked_a = masked_a | mask;
    }

    return masked_a;
}
```

EDIT: I've updated the loops to what I think are correct, although that is open to interpretation depending on what the expected answer is. Apologies for the earlier incorrect response, I was just pointing out the glaring error and that should probably have been a comment.

Answer (score 2):

1. switch `left` and `right` in original code since left is highest bit and right is lowest bit.
2. initialize masked_a to a
3. change `1>>j` to `1<<j`

Assume your left and right is starting from 1

```
int activate_bits(int a, int left, int right)
{
    int n, j, mask, masked_a = a;

    for (n = 0; n < right - 1; n++) {
        mask = 1 << n;
        masked_a = a | mask;
    }

    for (j = 31; j > 31 - left + 1; j--) {
        mask = 1 << j;
        masked_a = a | mask;
    }

    return masked_a;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

some functions to set, reset and write new value

```
unsigned set_bits(unsigned a, unsigned pos, unsigned size)
{
    unsigned mask = ((1 << size) - 1) << pos;
    return a |  mask;
}

unsigned reset_bits(unsigned a, unsigned pos, unsigned size)
{
    unsigned mask = ((1 << size) - 1) << pos;
    return a & ~(mask);
}


unsigned write_bits(unsigned a, unsigned newVal, unsigned pos, unsigned size)
{
    unsigned mask = ((1 << size) - 1);
    newVal &= mask;
    mask <<= pos;

    return (a & ~(mask)) | newVal << pos;
}
```

to make your units:

```
right = pos
left = pos + size - 1;
```

Comment: I don't think your `write_bits` function is useful - it's hard to define what it does, and OP doesn't need it. Also I suspect it's buggy, but I don't know what it should do, so cannot know for sure.

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: This is very close to what OP needs, and the only answer here which is O(1). So I gave it a +1.

Comment: @interjay  shows OP how to do such operations. If he wants to use `left` and `right` as the parameters I have provided the equations

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question. I've tried the solutions above, and none of them worked for me, since I think no one understood what you wanted exactly. I know it's been a year, but this worked for me, and I believe it's pretty simple:

```
int activate_bits(int a, int left, int right) {

    left = 31 - left;

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < left; i++) {
        a = a | (0x80000000 >> i);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < right; i++) {
        a = a | (1 << i);
    }

    return a;
}
```